# Cassandra 3.11.16 cannot be installed due to dependencies

Tags: cassandra

[Question]

- How can we resolve dependencies?

[Requirements]

- I want to install cassandra 3.11 series.
- I want to use AmazonLinux2023 as my operating system.
- I want to install Cassandra using dnf instead of tar.

[Status]

- I am building a Cassandra cluster on AWS using EC2.
- Tried to install Cassandra 3.11.16 on AmazonLinux2023.
- However, when running the installation with dnf, it failed to install because it could not resolve the dependencies.

[Configuration Information]

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.382.05.1 (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.382.05.1 (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)
```

```
# alternatives --config java

There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/jre/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 1
```

```
# alternatives --config javac

There is 1 program that provides 'javac'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin/javac

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 1
```

[Error]

- I have java installed but cannot resolve the "java-1.8.0-headless" dependency.

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:37:17 ago on Wed Sep 20 18:09:39 2023.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides java-1.8.0-headless needed by cassandra-3.11.16-1.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

[Construction Procedures]

- Install Java

```
dnf -y install java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel
```

- Install Python

```
cd /opt
dnf -y install gcc zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl-devel
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/Python-2.7.15.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.15.tgz
cd Python-2.7.15
./configure --enable-optimizations
make altinstall
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
cd ..
rm -fr Python-2.7.15*
```

- Add a repository

```
cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo
[cassandra]
name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/311x/
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS
EOF
```

- Install Cassandra

```
dnf update -y
dnf install -y cassandra jemalloc
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an environmental issue to me, not a problem with Cassandra itself. It looks like your package manager is not able to find your Java installation.

If you run this command, it should give you the version + distribution of JDK installed:

```
$ java -version
```

If it gives you an unexpected version, then you will need to reconfigure your environment. For example, it might report that Java 17 is installed or some other Java distribution.

Cassandra 3.x (or earlier releases) only works with Java 8. Support for Java 11 was added in C* 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-9608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608)). The upcoming C* 5.0 release (expected in late 2023) will add support for Java 17 ([CASSANDRA-16895](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16895)) and drop support for Java 8.

If Java 8 is not the default on your system, you'll need to run `alternatives` to change the Java provider:

```
$ sudo alternatives --config java
```

or since you've installed JDK 8, run:

```
$ sudo alternatives --config javac
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   
Java is installed with Amazon Corretto 8.   
The above was not a problem when 3.11.15 was installed.

Comment: That's because the dependencies fix for Java was added in C* 3.11.16 ([CASSANDRA-18751](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-18751)). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I understood that AmazonCorretto8 does not have Headless and therefore cannot install it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this problem by registering the Eclipse Temurin repository and installing the temurin-8-jdk.
However, since it is AmazonLinux2023 and refers to the repository for AmzonLinux2, there may be some problems in the future.
I also asked AWS(Japan) the following questions and received responses of unknown or none of the above.

- Are there any plans for AmazonCorretto8 to support headless?
- Is there a way to use a different distribution of OpenJDK with AmazonLinux2023?

I was also offered a workaround from the AWS side that java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless is used when using AmazonLinux2.

[procedure]

1. Repository registration.

```
cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/adoptium.repo 
[Adoptium]
name=Adoptium
baseurl=https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/rpm/amazonlinux/2/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public
EOF
```

2. Install temurin-8-jdk.

```
dnf update
dnf -y install temurin-8-jdk
```